# ASP.NET MVC3 Unobtrusive Validation and Hand Coded Element Question

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-validation

I understand with built in function to render UI controls like

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CustomerId)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerId)
```

The rendered Html will look like

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field CustomerId must be a number." data-val-required="The CustomerId field is required." id="CustomerId" name="CustomerId" type="text" value="" />
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="CustomerId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

All the attributes inside input elements are used to support unobtrusive validation feature.

But for some reason I cannot render  by using Html helper, but I have to hand code Html markup like

```
<select id="MyId" name="MyId" />
<%=Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MyId)%>
```

In this case how can I still make unobtrusive validation word without hard code all these attributes in select element?

Thanks

Hardy

Comment: Why not solve the rendering by Html helper rather than hand coding? What problems are you having with that.

Comment: Sometime I need to render some control by jQuery on the fly, but user input of that dynamic control binds to one field of my model, I need validation.

Answer (score 0):

Unobtrusive validation relies completely on this attributes to determine which validation it will apply to the element, you will have to hard code them in  your html is you dont want to use the helper, just make sure the name attribute of you select tag is equal to the property name it binds to.

Comment: I know the importance of these attributes to support unobtrusive validation. I am just curious anybody ever tried to dynamically add attributes on the fly by querying server side?